# dynamically set the propeties in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

i have the following code in c#

```
class1
{
 public string Body
        {
 set
            {
                byte[] bytesToEncode = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
                string encodedText = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesToEncode);
                this._body = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(encodedText);
            }
        }
}
```

now inside some another class i have to provide the string values to Body like

```
class my class
{
class1 c = null;
c.body = ???
}
```

Please help me out how to give the values dynamically to Body . I don't want to hard code the string literal.

regards
priya

Comment: How are you using the class that's setting the `c.body`?

Comment: What does "give the values dynamically to Body " mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you perhaps trying to initialize an instance of `class1`, like this?

```
class myClass
{
    private class1 c = new class1 { Body = "foo" };
}
```

Or, maybe you want to create it in the `myClass` constructor:

```
public class myClass
{
    private class1 c;

    public myClass(string body)
    {
        c = new class1 { Body = body };
    }
}
```

And then you create an instance of `myClass` by calling:

```
myClass mine = new myClass("foo");
```

If that's not what you're trying to do, then you need to provide a better second example, and some description.